# NestedRecyclerView's onBindViewHolder gettting called multiple times and not getting recycled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using nestedRecyclerView with Vertical parent recyclerview and horizontal child views. I have list of 10 items and each item contains a list for child recyclerview.

When I run the app, parent adapter's onbindviewholder getting called 10 items which is the total size of the parent list. I want to know why it is happening. It should call 4 or 5 onbindviewholder depending on the screen size but it is calling for all items which is unintended.

Parent Recyclerview initialization

```
homeRecyclerViewAdapter = new HomeRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), MR, (AppCompatActivity) getActivity());

            homeRecyclerViewAdapter.setDataList(homeArrayList);
            LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager3 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            mLinearLayoutManager3.setOrientation(CustomLinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            homeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager3);
            homeRecyclerView.setAdapter(homeRecyclerViewAdapter);
```

Parent Adapter -

```
public class HomeRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    List dataList;
    private Context mContext;
    Typeface MR;
    static String PACKAGE_NAME;
    Utils utils;
    CustomClickEvents customClickEvents;
    AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;

    public HomeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, Typeface MR, int type, CustomClickEvents customClickEvents) {

        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.MR = MR;
        this.customClickEvents = customClickEvents;
        utils = new Utils();

    }
    RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool pool;
    public HomeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, Typeface MR, AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity) {

        pool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();

        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.MR = MR;
        this.appCompatActivity = appCompatActivity;
        utils = new Utils();

    }

    public void setDataList(List upiAppsList) {
        this.dataList = upiAppsList;

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view;
        PACKAGE_NAME = mContext.getPackageName();

        if (viewType == Constants.HomePageViewTypes.TYPE_0) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_layout, null);
            return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == Constants.HomePageViewTypes.TYPE_1) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_layout, null);
            return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == Constants.HomePageViewTypes.TYPE_2) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_layout, null);
            return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, int position) {

        Log.d("recyclerview", "HomeRecyclerViewHolder onbindviewholder + pos" + position);

        Log.d("recyclerview", "HomeRecyclerViewHolder dataList.get(position):" + dataList.get(position));

        RecyclerViewHolder holder = (RecyclerViewHolder) itemViewHolder;
        holder.commonRecyclerViewAdapter.setDataList(((HomePageViewModel) dataList.get(position)).getDataList());


    }


    public void setbackgroundcolortoitem(int position, RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, boolean is_checked) {

        int modulus_position = position % 4;

        Log.d("tag", "position ---- > " + modulus_position);

    }

    class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        CommonRecyclerViewAdapter commonRecyclerViewAdapter;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mrecyclerview);
            mRecyclerView.setPadding((int) (8 * utils.getScreenDensity(mContext)), 0, 0, (int) (8 * utils.getScreenDensity(mContext)));
            // mRecyclerView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            commonRecyclerViewAdapter = new CommonRecyclerViewAdapter(mContext, MR, 6, appCompatActivity);

            LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager3 = new LinearLayoutManager(appCompatActivity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) {
                @Override
                public boolean checkLayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp) {
                    // force height of viewHolder here, this will override layout_height from xml
                    Log.d("upisdk", "HomeRecyclerView getwidth:" + getWidth());
                    lp.width = (int) (getWidth() / 1.6);
                    return true;
                }
            };
            mLinearLayoutManager3.setOrientation(CustomLinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager3);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(commonRecyclerViewAdapter);



        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int position = getLayoutPosition();

            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.mainlayout:


                    break;

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if (dataList.get(position) instanceof HomePageViewModel) {

            if (((HomePageViewModel) dataList.get(position)).getLayoutType() == Constants.HomePageViewTypes.TYPE_0) {
                return Constants.HomePageViewTypes.TYPE_0;
            }

        }

        return -1;

    }


}
```

I want parent onbindviewholder to get called for the items displaying currently on screen which is  the supposed behaviour of RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

Is the parent View of the Parent RecycleView a ScrollView or NestedScrollView, bro? If true, please remove it

Comment: No. Parent view is not ScrollView or NestedScrollView. It is linear Layout

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer to me. One of the primary purposes of the question's comment section is to ask for clarification or more details from the asker.